# Contador númerico

Tags: jquery, html5, css3, bootstrap-3, contador

estou fazendo uma página de controle para entrada e saída de equipamentos da empresa.
Estou usando Boostrap como framework, vocês poderiam me informar como eu faço um contador para gerenciar o número da OS. Ou algum link de ajuda na internet, video, etc.
 Imagino que com JQuery seja possível mas não tenho experiência com essa ferramenta.
  Pelo pouco conhecimento que tenho em programação web sei que preciso de um BD e algo para comunicar a página com este BD.[image: pagina]
Desde já obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi, você quer gravar essas informações em um Banco de Dados, certo ? Se sim, você vai precisar de uma linguagem de servidor (como PHP, Ruby etc) e não do jQuery.

Da uma olhada neste link: http://www.devmedia.com.br/php-e-mysql-conectando-e-exibindo-dados-de-forma-rapida-dica/28526

Abs

Comment: Gabriel bom dia,
Obrigado pela atenção vou dar uma olhada um amigo meu programador informou que irá me ajudar também.

Answer (score 0):

A sua tática arquitetural usando o framework bootstrap suporta os seus requisitos de renderização da camada de visão, porém não está listado a sua estratégia para atender a outros requisitos que é de back-end.

Geralmente não é implementado esse contador na camada de visão pois pode haver um erro entre o que está renderizado na tela e os dados do banco de dados.

Sugiro a implementação dessa contagem o mais perto possível da entidade do banco de dados. Caso sua tática arquitetural de back-end for Java EE, o contador pode ser persistido no banco de dados e por isso vai ter um campo na Entidade do JPA para armazená-lo, ou então inclua um campo transiente para realizar a contagem caso não seja interessante persistir esse dado que pode ser inferido por outros dados persistidos.

Answer (score 0):

Tu já consegue buscar, inserir ou alterar algo do banco de dados? Já fez isso em alguma tela?

Se sim, tu pode criar um campo no teu banco de dados do tipo inteiro, não permitindo valores nulos e auto incremento e como PK da tabela.

Deste modo ele vai sempre existir, vai ser único e vai estar na ordem de cadastro.

Assim sendo seria só buscar o campo no banco e mostrar na tela.

Acredito que isso resolveria o teu problema... agora se o usuário quiser alterar os dados, não coloque o campo como Primary Key (PK).

Comment: Isabela bom dia,
Obrigado pela atenção, um amigo meu programador informou o mesmo que você citou ele também irá me ajudar muito obrigado pela atenção.